# Testing Remember me functionality with Behat/Mink

Tags: behat, mink

I am trying to test a remember me functionality with Behat and Mink in a Symfony2 project. However, my approach is not working.

I tried the following:

```
#behat.yml

Scenario: Checking Remember me
  Given I am on "/"
  When  I fill in "username" with "john"
  And   I fill in "password" with "john"
  And   I check "remember_me"
  And   I press "Login"
  Then  I should be logged in
  When  I restart the browser
  Then  I should be logged in

Scenario: Not Checking Remember me
  Given I am on "/"
  When  I fill in "username" with "john"
  And   I fill in "password" with "john"
  And   I press "Login"
  Then  I should be logged in
  When  I restart the browser
  Then  I should be logged out
```

My feature context contains (among others) the following methods:

```
#FeatureContext.php

/**
 * @Then /^I should be logged in$/
 */
public function iShouldBeLoggedIn()
{
    $this->assertElementOnPage('.user-area');
}

/**
 * @Given /^I should be logged out$/
 */
public function iShouldBeLoggedOut()
{
    $this->assertElementNotOnPage('.user-area');
}

/**
 * @When /^I restart the browser$/
 */
public function iRestartTheBrowser()
{
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
    $session = new Session($driver);
    $session->start();
    $session->visit('/');
}
```

The problem lies within `iRestartTheBrowser()`. This is not doing what it is supposed to do. I am looking for a way to clear session data but keep cookies. Any help?

Comment: Btw, of course the first thing I tried was to reset or restart the session. Didn't work because cookies get deleted as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your spec may be better worded as

```
Scenario: Checking Remember me
    Given I have logged in before and selected remember me
    When I visit "some protected web page"
    Then I should be logged in
```

The `Given` can set state for *remember me*, and perhaps the context for this can help you isolate the need to reset the session?

The above is also easier to read for laypeople and developers alike

Comment: Good food for thougt, thanks. I am new to Behat and still figuring out how much I should describe single workflows and how much I should keep functional tests in mind. I will give it a try.